# Прокрутка контента в блоке при сколле вне его

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать прокрутку контента в блоке, если скроллить вне этого блока. 
[codepen](https://codepen.io/sergo/pen/OYQGKw).
Извините конечно за неприличный вопрос, но я уже все облазил. Нет решения нигде. Сам не могу написать, т.к. не силен в js. Может есть у кого готовый пример. Спасибо

```css
.content{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-top: calc(50% - 300px);
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Нормально - никак: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/750420/178988. 2. Вот адекватный вариант, если есть что скроллить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760433/178988. 3. И ещё немного магии: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/550320/178988.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Задачка получилась скорее про гугл, чем про JS )) 

Почти решил, но проблема в том, что scrollHeight не учитывает высоту элемента, который реально виден, а указывает только на пиксели, которые стоят "за кулисами". Поэтому скроллятся не идеально синхронно.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/h2v9cw1o/)

(позже добью со свежей головой. Или может вы)

```js
(function(){

var x = document.getElementById('content');
var scroll = x.scrollHeight;
var win = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
  /* Идея была в том, чтобы разделив общие пиксели для скролла блока - на общий 
  скролл окна, получить коэффициент, который даст синхронный скролл*/
  x.scrollTop = scroll / win * (document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  
  console.clear();
  console.log( scroll );
  console.log( win );
  console.log( x.scrollTop );
  console.log( document.documentElement.scrollTop );
});

})();
```

```css
.content{
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0; right: 0;
}

body {height: 2000px;}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, pariatur delectus maiores eveniet, dolorum repudiandae facilis explicabo velit ea molestiae sequi provident, rerum unde! Earum eos illo voluptatum quam numquam?
</div>
```

Comment: Я добавил высоту блока к переменной - scroll. И теперь четенько. Спасибо большое!